# Multiset of objects

Tags: c++, set, multiset

I have `multiset < Class1 > myset`;
so I create a new object: `Class1* c1 = new Class1();`
I was expecting to be able to `myset.insert(c1)` or `myset.insert(new Class1());` but none of them work.

```
class Class1{
 int time;
public:
  CLass1(int t) : time(t) {}
  bool operator<(Class1 &c2) {return time < c2.time;}
}
```

How is inserting objects different from inserting integers? I was able to insert ints.

Comment: What do you mean by *none of them work*? Did you hit a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: In your description, you're inserting *pointers* - not objects.  And the set expects *objects* (hint hint).

Comment: Compilation error: no matching function for call to ...

Comment: I had < operator commented out for some reason. Now when I dereference c1, it doesn't give me errors when iserting.

Comment: Your `operator<` is `const`-incorrect: its argument should be `const`, and the function itself should be `const`: `bool operator<(const Class1 &c2) const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition, `myset` holds `Class1` object, while `c1` is a pointer to `Class1` object. So that's the type problem.

Either you use `myset` to hold pointer to objects -- `multiset<Class1 *> myset`, or copy the newly created object into `myset` -- `myset.insert(*c1); delete c1;`. Note that container requires object must be copyable and assignable, and should be comparable by implementing `operator<`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it fixed! So multiset container must be sorted? I didn't have < operator and it was giving me all the errors.

Comment: Yes, I think internally `(multi)map` and `(multi)set` are implemented as balanced tree. `<unordered_map>` and `<unordered_set>` in c++0x provides hash table implementation.